# Having trouble getting this Google Chrome Extension icon right

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, icon, photoshop-effects

This is how my icon is looking now. I want to remove that "alpha" or something, that grey square.

[image]

I want it full like

[image]  [image]

**Chrome suggested me to do this:**

> Upload an icon image that represents this item, and ensure it complies
>   with the following: 128x128 total pixels For square icons, use alpha
>   to make 16 of the 128 pixels per side transparent (96x96 visual
>   weight) For circular icons, the visual icon should be 112x112 (use
>   alpha to make the remaining pixels transparent) For other icon shapes,
>   use alpha to maintain the same 96x96 visual weight.

I tried but couldn't get this done? Any way out?

I want a full square icon with color #A4C639 (android green).

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I tried but...` What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?!  The shape isn't perfect but just to confirm that you want a puzzle piece that looks like this and the rest is transparent?!

[image]

How to make it:
1. Draw a square 96px on an empty 128px by 128px layer
2. Then with the selection tool cut out the holes
3. Draw the circles to your square
4. Double click the layer and check `Bevel and Emboss`
5. Use this settings:

[image]

Then save as PNG-24, PNG-8 or GIF.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very simple shape - just recreate it in Illustrator color it the green color you need and export in any format/size needed.

Comment: What about that alpha and 16px transperant?

Comment: Also, I dont know and have Illustrator, any way out buddy?

Comment: export as png or gif which supports transparent backgrounds you can outsource on fiverr.com

Comment: There are other editors -- no need to require Illustrator (and he hardly needs vector editing capabilities here). Suggesting he shell out $5 to outsource such a simple task is awfully silly.

Comment: @nikhil You could try [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/), it's open source and free.

Comment: @Yisela - The "therefore" is not correct. While most open source is indeed free, it's perfectly possible to have commercial (to pay) open source software.

Comment: @stevenvh Thanks for that! Corrected. I hesitated when I was writing it, I thought all open source derived programs also had to be open source or share the same license.